# Consolidating Elements of a List

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples:

`[('fruit', 'O'), ('is', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('subject', 'O'), ('of', 'O'), ('a', 'O'), ('Roald', 'PERSON'), ('Dahl', 'PERSON'), ('children', 'O'), ("'s", 'O'), ('book', 'O'), ('?', 'O')]`

I want to reduce this list to:

`[('fruit', 'O'), ('is', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('subject', 'O'), ('of', 'O'), ('a', 'O'), ('Roald Dahl', PERSON'), ('children', 'O'), ("'s", 'O'), ('book', 'O'), ('?', 'O')]`

That is, any consecutive tuples whose second value is not `'O'` should  have their first value concatenated. This should work for list of any length, and for any number of consecutive tuples to be joined.

Comment: Can there be any non consecutive items with the same value?

Comment: Yes, they should pass through as is. It's only if there's >1 in a row that they need to be joined.

Comment: are a,b ... really vars, object names or string charcters that you should quote

Comment: Does the list always has 5 elements ?

Comment: @f5r5e5d they're strings

Comment: @Elmex80s no, it can be of length `n`

Comment: @ColinRicardo since you have another identical question, please delete this one.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I can't delete this one for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group utilizing the last element in each tuple:

```
import itertools
s = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 4), (10, 4), (7, 8)]
s = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(s, key=lambda x:x[-1])]
final_s = [(sum(i[0] for i in b), a) for a, b in s]
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (18, 4), (7, 8)]
```

Edit: regarding your new, non numeric list of tuples, you can try this:

```
from functools import reduce
def remove(data, to_avoid='O'):
   s = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby(data, key=lambda x:x[-1])]
   final_s = [x for i in [b if a == to_avoid else [(reduce(lambda c, d: "{} {}".format(c, d), [h[0] for h in b]), a)] for a, b in s] for x in i]
   return final_s


>>remove([('fruit', 'O'), ('is', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('subject', 'O'), ('of', 'O'), ('a', 'O'), ('Roald', 'PERSON'), ('Dahl', 'PERSON'), ('children', 'O'), ("'s", 'O'), ('book', 'O'), ('?', 'O')])
```

Output:

```
[('fruit', 'O'), ('is', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), ('subject', 'O'), ('of', 'O'), ('a', 'O'), ('Roald Dahl', 'PERSON'), ('children', 'O'), ("'s", 'O'), ('book', 'O'), ('?', 'O')]
```

---

For those of us less comprehension aware, and using operator.itemgetter instead of the lamda's

```
import itertools, operator
item0 = operator.itemgetter(0)
item1 = operator.itemgetter(1)
result = []
for k, g in itertools.groupby(s, key=item1):
    if k != 'O':
        result.append((' '.join(map(item0, g)),k))
    else:
        result.extend(g)
```

Comment: This will count the non consecutive ones, which isn't what's wanted.

Comment: @DanielRoseman if it isn't sorted first the non consecutive tuples should show up separate in the final sequence.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it behaves correctly.

Comment: Mind if I add something?

Comment: @wwii please, go ahead.