# Concatenating elements of tuples in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples:

```
[('fruit', 'O'), ('is', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), 
 ('subject', 'O'), ('of', 'O'), ('a', 'O'), 
 ('Roald', 'PERSON'), ('Dahl', 'PERSON'), ('children', 'O'), 
 ("'s", 'O'), ('book', 'O'), ('?', 'O')]`
```

I want to reduce this list to:

```
[('fruit', 'O'), ('is', 'O'), ('the', 'O'), 
 ('subject', 'O'), ('of', 'O'), ('a', 'O'), 
 ('Roald Dahl', 'PERSON'), ('children', 'O'), 
 ("'s", 'O'), ('book', 'O'), ('?', 'O')]`
```

That is, any consecutive tuples whose second value is not 'O' should have their first values concatenated. This should work for a list of any length, and for any number of consecutive tuples to be joined.

### Attempt

```
def join_tags(list_tags):
  res = []
  last_joined = None
  last_seen = (None, None)

  for tup in list_tags:
    if tup[1] == 'O':
      res.append(tup)
      last_joined = None
    else:
      if tup[1] == last_seen[1]:
        if last_joined:
          new_tup = (last_joined[0] + ' ' + tup[0], tup[1])
          last_joined = new_tup
          res.append(new_tup)
        else:
          new_tup = (tup[0] + ' ' + tup[0], tup[1])
          res.append(new_tup)
          last_joined = new_tup
      else:
        res.append(tup)
        last_joined = None
    last_seen = tup

  return res
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far, and why do you think it didn't work?

Comment: Didn't you ask this question here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48244632/consolidating-elements-of-a-list/48244705#48244705

Comment: Colin, please don't keep asking this question over and over again. If the answers solve your problem, please use them. Would also help if you voted on, and marked them accepted as solving your problem. If you keep doing this, then your questions will be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you've used `itertools`, it has a lot of useful routines for operations like this. One function, aptly named `groupby`, will be useful here.

Edit: Thanks to @juanpa.arrivillaga for the [improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48246315/concatenating-elements-of-tuples-in-a-list/48246337#comment83475392_48246337) using `operator`.

```
import itertools
from operator import itemgetter

r = []
for k, g in itertools.groupby(l, key=itemgetter(1)):
    if k == 'O':
        r.extend(g)
    else:
        r.append((' '.join([i[0] for i in g]), k))
```

```
print(r)
[('fruit', 'O'),
 ('is', 'O'),
 ('the', 'O'),
 ('subject', 'O'),
 ('of', 'O'),
 ('a', 'O'),
 ('Roald Dahl', 'PERSON'),
 ('children', 'O'),
 ("'s", 'O'),
 ('book', 'O'),
 ('?', 'O')]
```

here, `l` is your input list of tuples.

Comment: You should use `itemgetter(1)` instead of a boolean, since you actually want to re-use the group-by key, allowing you not to have to materialize an axuiliary list. e.g. `if k == 'O': r.extend(g) else:new_dat.append((' '.join([x[0] for x in g]), k))`

Comment: Of course, that wouldn't be equivalent, but I suspect taht if there are two different things that are not 'PERSON' they are supposed to be grouped separately...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you, that's a great improvement, and I suspect it's more along the lines of what OP was looking for anyway.

Comment: I went ahead and deleted the `g = list(g)` since it's no longer necessary :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ah, how could I forget! `extend` accepts a generator. Thanks again. :-)